# page tab's signed_request occasionally not populated

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

I have a page tab application.  Sometimes when a logged in user clicks the tab name from the Facebook page, the form post "signed_request" data is being passed in is empty.

Any ideas as to how this can happen?  It is sporadic and doesn't seem to be locked to one specific user account.  I have oauth2 set to true in the settings, so according to Facebook's api documentation, I should always be passed signed_request in the form post data.

Comment: I just earned a tumbleweed badge with this question.  Where or where is the support from Facebook???

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Anybody got any answer?

Comment: I also ran into this problem. You can try to look at this [link](http://www.violato.net/blog/php/71-uncaught-curlexception-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cert-is-ok-when-implementing-facebook-connect). This helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the work-around I've figured out.

*If there is no signed_request form post parameter, then I display an error screen to the user and ask the user to refresh the page.  This usually fixes the issue on the second request, and the page is sent a proper signed_request form post.*

Lack of Facebook support and involvement in the facebook stackoverflow section is very disconcerting.  It wouldn't be that bad, if it wasn't that Facebook had mandated use of this forum for the entirety of their API support.  :(

Comment: Make sure you're including your subdomain (if necessary) in your page tab url. My site had a general redirect to www, but I didn't include www in my tab url in the app settings. It kept prepending/redirecting to www, hence losing all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, was helped by:

[Cannot access Facebook signed_request with an iframe tab](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5874323/cannot-access-facebook-signed-request-with-an-iframe-tab)

In my case the site hosting the app was doing a 301 redirect because the app url I gave Facebook contained capital letters. The redirect changed POST to GET and lost the signed_request.

Comment: Interesting.  Any idea why my web cluster would do this sporadically?  You'd think if the url was not in the correct case, it would do this with every other request (50% of the time since the first would be upper/lower and the second would be all lower).  However in my situation it only does this about 1 or 2% of the time.